# dojo: a tab currently selected within the tab container (dijit.layout.TabContainer) does not visually change to show that it is the selected tab

Tags: dojo

I have updated dojo from 1.61 to 1.81 and now the tab (dijit.layout.ContentPane) that is currently selected within the tab container (dijit.layout.TabContainer) does not visually change to show that it is the selected tab.  With dojo 1.61 as the user clicked on different tabs the clicked on tab would get a little bigger and change color from blue to white and this does not happen after upgrading to 1.81.  How can I get the same behavior with dojo 1.81?

Answer (score 0):

I figure out the problem was that I was still pointing to the dojo 1.61 for the styles instead of dojo 1.81 and once I fix this then the tabs change visually after I click on it.